# Outlook RPC server unavailable after sending email through .Net app

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I've just started having a look at interoperability between .Net and Office apps, particularly Outlook. I've managed to get emails to send through Outlook but for some reason the RPC server for outlook shuts down after I've sent an email (if outlook wasn't already running). Here's my code:

```
private void CreateEmailItem(string subjectEmail, string toEmail, string bodyEmail)
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg =  (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    try
    {
        Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;
        oMsg.Subject = subjectEmail;
        Outlook.Recipients oRecips =  (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(toEmail);
        oRecip.Resolve();
        oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html><div style=font-size:16px; font-face:consolas;>" + bodyEmail + "</font></body></div></html>";
        oMsg.Send();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oMsg);
        oApp.Quit();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

So an error is thrown when I try to call the outlook applications Quit() method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oMsg);** line of code. There is no need to release underlying COM objects if you use the GC.Collect method.

Also I'd recommend declaring the an *Application* object at the global scope.

Comment: tried declaring the application globally but it still closes when an email is sent.

Comment: Did you try to remove the FinalReleaseComObject call?

Comment: yes i removed that too, the problem is though, the outlook application closes as soon as `oMsg.Send();` is called